# How do you find 2 variables in a quadrilateral, only knowing the other two?

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

If you know the angles of 2 sides of an irregular quadrilateral, how do you find out the other 2?

Many Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Three angles in quadrilateral define the fourth, since the angle sum is fixed. But when you only have two angles, and nothing else, then the quadrilateral isn't fully determined by this.

Answer (score -1):

Ok to find the other two I feel like you should solve it this way:
Sum of angles in a quadrilateral $=360$
You say.for example:the figures are $92,2x,2x,52 =360$

\begin{align}144+4x&=360\\
4x&=360-144\\
4x&=216 \\
\end{align}
Divide both sides by $4, x=54$.